# How can I implement a progress bar on a non-iterable line of code?

Tags: python, progress-bar

I have several lines of code in my Python script that take anywhere from 20 minutes to several hours depending on the size of the files being read. I am wondering if it would be possible to implement a progress bar that would track the progress towards completion.

From the documentation that I've read, I understand that tqdm and progressbar2 are often used in cases where there is a for loop.

This is what my code looks like:

```
gjson2 = rasterstats.zonal_stats(polygons, raster, prefix='xyz_', geojson_out=True,all_touched=False,categorical=True)
```

The code serves to intersect the polygons file (.shp) with the raster file (.adf) to extract raster values. Is there a way I can rewrite the code to make it iterable? Or manipulate tqdm or progressbar2 to work in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: To count progress you must know in advance both the end point, i.e., the 'total' to be processed in whatever unit, and the current point. Without this it's not possible.
 
Even if the file size is known (not a stream) *and* it's proportional to needed processing time (not a given), you could estimate total time by experimentation, and setup a timer (`import threading` [?]) to fire every so many sub-units of the total time.

However, this is more of a hack as it most likely won't work well in general as CPU speeds vary with different machines.

Answer (score 1):

I have not had much luck putting a progress bar into the python console effectively, but if it helps, https://geektechstuff.com/2018/12/07/creating-a-progress-bar-python/ has some info on tkinter window progress bars. An example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
main = Tk()

def foo(progressbar):
    progressbar.start()
    for _ in range(50):
        progressbar.step(10)
        ###Perform some Function
        progressbar.update_idletasks()
    progressbar.stop()       
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(main, mode='indeterminate', length=696)
progressbar.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=100, rowspan=100, sticky=W, pady=4, padx=3)
foo(progressbar)
main.mainloop()
```

The code above works for me (python 3x windows 10).

Alternatively you could install `progressbar` on  PyPI to show a loading bar in the python console. Example:

```
import progressbar
from time import sleep
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=20, \
    widgets=[progressbar.Bar('=', '[', ']'), ' ', progressbar.Percentage()])
bar.start()
for i in xrange(20):
    bar.update(i+1)
    sleep(0.1)
bar.finish()
```

Also: the '\r' (carriage return) character is supposed to reset the cursor to the beginning of the line. I'm not 100% sure if this works on all systems, but I know it does on Linux and OSX:

```
from time import sleep
import sys

for i in range(21):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    # the exact output you're looking for:
    sys.stdout.write("[%-20s] %d%%" % ('='*i, 5*i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.25)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think the issue is not how to create a progress bar per se but how to do so for 'black box' functions over which you have no control and which do not provide some call-out based on progress.

Comment: Not too sure, but unless you use the progressbar module, or make some way to estimate the time it will take (which will slow down the process) that may not be possible without knowledge of how long it will take; at least using a basic progress bar will show about how far the progress is.